# Apache Camel deleting AWS S3 bucket's folder

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-camel

I am testing a route which accesses a file from an AWS S3 bucket's sales folder. The problem I am facing is the moment all files are read from the folder, Camel deletes the folder. I understand that there is no notion of folder in S3. The file names' are prefixed with folder name.

How can I prevent the folder in S3 from getting deleted when all files are read and deleted.

Here is my route

`from("aws-s3://departments?amazonS3Client=#s3Client&region=eu-west-1&prefix=sales")    .to("file:C:\temp?fileName=${header.CamelAwsS3Key}");`

Comment: What version of Camel do you use

Comment: I am using Camel version 2.18.3

Answer (score 1):

Know your Camel version would really help, by the way to avoid the deletion of the file you're consuming you can use the deleteAfterRead option and set it to false.

https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-aws/src/main/docs/aws-s3-component.adoc

In this way you should be able to avoid the deletion and at the same time, each time the consumer will poll you'll get the same set of file. Be aware of this last behavior.

Comment: I had experimented with option deleteAfterRead. But it does not suit my purpose as I need to delete the file once it is read. I am beginning to wonder maintaining the folder after deleting all files in S3 bucket's folder via Camel may just not be possible as AWS S3 does not have the concept of file folder. I would appreciate if somebody can help me with a solution that works for my needs.

Comment: @ArifShaikh Did you figure out how to solve this issue? Possibly a way to skip processing of folders themselves, while reading objects within the folders?