# Apache Camel eats S3 "folders" created programatically, but not ones created in AWS S3 Console

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-camel

We have an Apache Camel app that is supposed to read files in a certain directory structure in S3, process the files (generating some metadata based on the folder the file is in), submit the data in the file (and metadata) to another system and finally put the consumed files into a different bucket, deleting the original from the incoming bucket.

The behaviour I'm seeing is that when I programatically create the directory structure in S3, those "folders" are being consumed, so the dir structure disappears.

*I know S3 technically does not have folders, just empty files ending in `/`.*

**The twist** here is that any "folder" created in the S3 Console, are NOT consumed, they stay there as we want them to. Any folders created via AWS CLI, or `boto3` are immediately consumed.

The problem is that we do need the folders to be created with automation, there are too many to do by hand.

I've reached out to AWS Support, and they just tell me that there are no differences between how the Console creates folders, and how the CLI does it. Support confirmed that the command I used in CLI is correct.

I think my issue is similar to [Apache Camel deleting AWS S3 bucket's folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47639156/apache-camel-deleting-aws-s3-buckets-folder) , but that has no answer...

How can I get Camel to not "eat" any folders?

Comment: just a hint: you can draw attention also on old questions by setting a bounty on those

Comment: Are you aware that the AWS cli and boto3 don't create empty object folder placeholders like the web console does when you make a folder in it?

Comment: Could you please expand on that point, AC? What would I need to do to make boto3 create the folder in the same way as S3 Console?

Comment: Upload several files using the CLI/Boto3 with `/` in them, the tools will display the result as a folder, but when you remove those files via any means, the folders disappear.  When you create a "folder" with the console, it creates an empty "placeholder" that will stay around if you remove all of the files that shar the prefix.

Comment: Yes, so I created the folder with `aws s3api put-object --bucket $MYBUCKET --key 'fromcli/'`, which AWS Support claims is correct....

Comment: That will not behave the same as the web console does.  To have a similar object created, you'll need something like `aws s3api put-object --bucket $MYBUCKET --content-type "application/x-directory; charset=UTF-8" --key from_cli/`

Comment: Ooooh, that seems to have done the trick!! Please write it as an answer, so I can mark it as accepted and boost your karma, AC!! ❤️